# Can't access Collection from Client... (Meteorjs Iron:router 'pathFor couldn't find a route named undefined')

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router, meteor-autoform

I can't display items from my collection on a page in my MeteorJS app.
I am using `aldeed:autoform` and `iron:router`.

In my JS console I always see on page load:

> pathFor couldn't find a route named undefined

I have published and subscribed to the collection and written a helper function which should make the data accessible from the relevant template. Do I need to do something different when using Autoform and iron:router?

Comment: The relevant part would be where you use this `pathFor` since it is clear that whatever you have written resolved to `pathFor undefined` which IronRouter does not like.

Comment: Thanks...

That was my first thought to check as well, but I'm not using a pathFor anywhere in my code...

Comment: Then you have to identify the piece of code that provokes the error. For that, you can either remove code until the error disappears, or start fresh and place back code until the error reappears. Then, post your working code (without error) and the failing code (with the error), explaining what you try to achieve.

Comment: pathFor would be in html, not js, in case you only looked for it in your js files. I haven't yet come across a package that defines and uses its own iron-router routes. If such a package exists and you are using it then at some point you're probably passing in invalid parameters or omitting some required parameter that deals with a route.

Answer (score -2):

You need to define a route in iron router with the given path name. Something like:

```
{{pathFor 'someRouteName'}}
```

And a route defined as follows:

```
Router.route('someRouteName');
```

in your router.js file.

Comment: Op very explicitly said in a comment that he is not "using a pathFor anywhere in [his] code", thus the issue comes from code in a lib, provoked by a misuse of said lib or less likely by a bug. Are you sure explaining how to use a `pathFor` is going to help?